# MVC JavaScript redirect that I need to pass a UserGuid into?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, redirect, razor

I have an tool that allows people to update their username. This tool has many tabs, and each action has a url parameter for the UserGuid. When the user changes their username, a partial view displays a message saying "The user has been updated successfully". I have just a simple javascript function to redirect the user back to the user details page after 2 seconds. The only problem is the action/method requires the UserGuid in order to function properly. So as of right now, I am getting an error saying that it's null. How can I pass this userguid in the javascript function that way the redirect will work properly?

Here is the partial view:

```
@{
var umessage = TempData["message"];
}
<div class="form_section">
<div class="form_item">
    <div class="frm_label">
        @umessage
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserGuid)
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("UserInfo", "User")';
}, 2000);
</script>
```

As you'll notice, I have a hidden field for the UserGuid. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Url.Action accepts route parameters. This should work for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("UserInfo", "User", new { userId = mode.UserGuid })';
}, 2000);
</script>
```

You might change the the parameter name though according to what your action accepts. I am not sure what parameter name your UserInfo action has for the id.

Comment: My parameter name accepts a "uniqueUserId" as the Guid. The only problem with this is that i've tried this. You can see on the html that I've posted I have a hidden field for UserGuid, and even though I pass that parameter through the url action, i get the null reference exception error on the uniqueUserId parameter.

Comment: Yes I see that you have the hidden UserGuid, but you don't seem to pass UserGuid to Url.Action method as route parameters.

Comment: I've tried that, when I do have it in the url route parameter it keeps giving me the null reference exception. I'm curious why it would do that. Even when I debug the program, it shows it's getting the userguid properly.

Comment: If it gives you null reference exception, than most likely at that point your Model itself is null. Make sure that it is not null, this will help: @Url.Action("UserInfo", "User", new { uniqueUserId =  model != null ? model.UserGuid.ToString() : string.Empty  })